# Moviepy - Output video not playable

Tags: python-3.x, moviepy

I'm using the library `moviepy` on Linux Mint 18.1.

Specifically, it's `moviepy 0.2.3.2` on `python 3.5.2`

Since I'm getting started, I tried this simple script, which should concatenate two videos one after the other:

```
import moviepy.editor as mp

video1 = mp.VideoFileClip("short.mp4")
video2 = mp.VideoFileClip("motivation.mp4")

final_video = mp.concatenate_videoclips([video1,video2])
final_video.write_videofile("composition.mp4")
```

The two videos are short random videos that I downloaded from YouTube. They both play perfectly, both with VLC and the standard video player provided with Linux Mint.

The script runs fine with no errors, with the final message:

```
[MoviePy] >>>> Building video composition.mp4
[MoviePy] Writing audio in compositionTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3
100%|██████████████████████████████| 1449/1449 [00:23<00:00, 59.19it/s]
[MoviePy] Done.
[MoviePy] Writing video composition.mp4
100%|██████████████████████████████| 1971/1971 [11:34<00:00,  2.84it/s]
[MoviePy] Done.
[MoviePy] >>>> Video ready: composition.mp4
```

The file is indeed created, and it also have a size (about 20 MB). However, when I try to play it, nothing happens: it seems to be corrupted. The standard video player even tells me that "there is no video stream to be played".

If I try to do the same with the interactive console, and use `final_video.preview()`, I get an `AttributeError`, along with this traceback:

```
In [5]: final_video.preview()
Exception in thread Thread-417:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-211>", line 2, in preview
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/moviepy/audio/io/preview.py", line 49, in preview
    sndarray = clip.to_soundarray(tt,nbytes=nbytes, quantize=True)
  File "<decorator-gen-184>", line 2, in to_soundarray
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py", line 107, in to_soundarray
    fps = self.fps
AttributeError: 'CompositeAudioClip' object has no attribute 'fps'
```

and the video seems frozen at the first frame.

I don't have any clue, since everything seems to work fine (except with the preview, which doesn't work because of the error). I tried to reinstall `ffmpeg`, but no succes: everything is exactly the same. Without any useful error, I can't figure out how to fix this problem. Can anyone help me?

EDIT: What are the 4 magic letters? **R-T-F-M**! I solved the problem by setting the kwarg `method` of `mp.concatenate_videoclips` to `compose`, since the original videos have a different frame size.

Comment: moviepy version?

Comment: Interesting. I though it would be [this bug](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/407). But you already have some newer version, where this was fixed (v0.2.3.1). Maybe this fix was not enough. So if your videos have different fps; you might check moviepy's sources to see what's going on. Or convert both videos to the same fps  before using moviepy (yeah, annoying).

Comment: pretty close, but the `AttributeError` here is related to `CompositeAudioClip`, not `VideoClip`. In the issue tracker, @zulko states that " `concatenate` will only attribute fps to the final clip if all the clips have the same fps, otherwise it's an ambigous case" and "..make the default fps as the largest fps in the list". This is exactly the behaviour I experience here: one clip has exactly 30.0 fps, the other 29.999..., and if I check `final_video.fps` from the interactive console, I get 30.0 fps. So, this shouldn't be the problem

Comment: I would try the same code with two equal-fps inputs. Just for debugging.

Comment: Ahhh.. too bad, I tried to convert the video using the command `ffmpeg -i <input_video> -r 30 <output_video>`, succesfully converting it to 30 fps, but no luck: it's still the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To hopefully figure out what's going on, I decided to take a more systematic approach, following these steps:

1. Create a virtual environment with no packages other than `moviepy` and its dependencies
2. Use videos from a different source
3. Try different codecs and/or other different parameters
4. Dig into the source code of `moviepy`
5. <strike>Sacrifice a goat to the Angel of Light, the Deceiver, the Father of Lies, the Roaring Lion, Son of Perdition Satan Lucifer</strike>

In each case I will this script (`test.py`):

```
import moviepy.editor as mp

video1 = mp.VideoFileClip("short.mp4")
video2 = mp.VideoFileClip("motiv_30.mp4")

final_video = mp.concatenate_videoclips([video1,video2])
final_video.write_videofile("composition.mp4")
```

with some minor changes, when needed. I'll update this post as I follow the steps.

**1. Create a virtual environment**

I created a virtual environment using `virtualenv`, activated it and installed `moviepy` with `pip`. This is the output of `pip freeze`:

```
decorator==4.0.11
imageio==2.1.2
moviepy==0.2.3.2
numpy==1.13.3
olefile==0.44
Pillow==4.3.0
tqdm==4.11.2
```

All with `python 3.5.2`.

After running `test.py`, the video is created, with no apparent problems. However, the video can't be played, neither by VLC nor by the default video player of Linux Mint 18.1.

Then, I noticed that `mp.concatenate_videoclips` has the kwarg `method`, which is by default set to `chain`. In the documentation, I read that:

```
- method="compose", if the clips do not have the same
  resolution, the final resolution will be such that no clip has
   to be resized.
```

So, I tried to use the kwarg `method="compose"`, since the two videos have different frame sizes and... *it worked*. I am an idiot. Oh well, no goats for Satan, I suppose. Lesson learned: **RTFM**

Comment: I had a different issue: I my rendered video contained parts where is was corrupted,and other parts where it was completely fine. Changing the method to "compose" fixed the issue. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @RealA10N ahah! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same trouble.
I fond the solution at https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/FAQ.html
It turns out that the video cannot have a odd ratio like 1080 x 351, so you just have to check if it's not even them add ou subtract one from that.

Comment: so strange but that applied in my case as well

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. After trying many other modules, I still couldn't solve it except the 'OpenCV-python':`import cv2` and it output video format with 'avi'. Sadly, I have a problem changing the play speed (duration between every graph/frame) and couldn't find an answer for it (maybe lack of attempts).

Then, out of luck and trying, I could provide an alternative answer. Perhaps your default media players don't support it (tried and failed in both windows and Ubuntu), showing error like this: **decoder is required to play the file, but is not installed**.

Just try another, 'VCL media player' works very well in my case.

Comment: No, in my case was simply a matter of trying to put together two videos with different resolution (different frame sizes? It's been so much time ago :D) and not giving the `mp.concatenate_videoclips()` function the appropriate kwarg. You say you have a problem changing the video speed? What do you mean? Perhaps you are referring to the framerate?

Comment: Though we are in different cases, we had same output and non-playable video. Yours was putting together 2 videos, mine was putting together many images. Yes, video speed means framerate in my case, how many frames in 1 second. I was thinking my proposed answer may solve your problem about non-playable.